# Is is possible to start and Oracle SQL Procedure with a CTE?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have a CTE that I know works, but I want to use it as a procedure so I can parameterize some of the queries within it. Here is the code I tried to run to create the procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VATIS_OWNER.getEnvVariables(PF IN VARCHAR, SN IN VARCHAR) AS
BEGIN
--Joins environemt variables from TESTCASES and ENVIRONMENTS tables and transposes result into columns 'ColumnName' and 'ColumnValue' and the ProfileId
--Is used by getAllDynamicData and unioned with results from sp_getProfileDetails
with
 cte as (
SELECT
T.TestcaseID,
T.ProfileID,
T.TrustID,
T.DNIS,
T.TESTID,
T.ACDID,
--Must be 8 digits long, so leading 0's are added
SUBSTR(CONCAT('00000000',T.testcaseid),-8, 8) as TestCaseNo,
T.HostId,
E.TFN
FROM TESTCASES T 
FULL JOIN ENVIRONMENTS E ON T.ENV_NAME = E.ENV_NAME
--Only returns env vars associated with testcase @SN
where T.TestcaseID = SN
),
cte2 as (
Select A.ProfileID
      ,B.*
From  cte A 
--Transpose happens here
Cross Apply (  SELECT 'TestcaseID' AS ColumnName,A.TestcaseID AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 'ProfileID' AS ColumnName,A.ProfileID AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 'TrustID' AS ColumnName,A.TrustID AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 'DNIS' AS ColumnName,SUBSTR(A.DNIS,-7,7) AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 'TESTID' AS ColumnName,A.TESTID AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 'ACDID' AS ColumnName,A.ACDID AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 'TestCaseNo' AS ColumnName,A.TestCaseNo AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 'HostId' AS ColumnName,A.HostId AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 'TFN' AS ColumnName,A.TFN AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
               SELECT 'INVALIDANI' AS ColumnName,SUBSTR(CONCAT(A.TestcaseID ,A.TESTID),-10,10) AS ColumnValue FROM DUAL
             ) B
)
select distinct * from cte2 where profileID = PF;
END getEnvVariables;
```

If I replace SN and PF with string values and run just the CTE and query, it works. And an equivalent version works as a Stored Procedure in SQL Server, but when I try to create this procedure in Oracle, I get this compile error:

```
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Any idea why I can't use this in a procedure? I am more familiar with SQL Server than Oracle, so if I've forgotten something please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the select result from this procedure, You have to use a SYS_REFCURSOR as below -

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE vatis_owner.Getenvvariables(pf IN VARCHAR, 
                                                        sn IN VARCHAR,
                                                        res OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
  BEGIN 
    --Joins environemt variables from TESTCASES and ENVIRONMENTS tables and transposes result into columns 'ColumnName' and 'ColumnValue' and the ProfileId
    --Is used by getAllDynamicData and unioned with results from sp_getProfileDetails 
    OPEN res FOR
    WITH cte AS 
    ( 
              SELECT    t.testcaseid, 
                        t.profileid, 
                        t.trustid, 
                        t.dnis, 
                        t.testid, 
                        t.acdid, 
                        --Must be 8 digits long, so leading 0's are added 
                        Substr(Concat('00000000',t.testcaseid),-8, 8) AS testcaseno, 
                        t.hostid, 
                        e.tfn 
              FROM      testcases t 
              full join environments e 
              ON        t.env_name = e.env_name 
                        --Only returns env vars associated with testcase @SN 
              WHERE     t.testcaseid = sn ), cte2 AS 
    ( 
           SELECT a.profileid , 
                  b.* 
           FROM   cte a 
                  --Transpose happens here 
                  cross apply 
                  ( 
                         SELECT 'TestcaseID' AS columnname, 
                                a.testcaseid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'ProfileID' AS columnname, 
                                a.profileid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'TrustID' AS columnname, 
                                a.trustid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'DNIS'              AS columnname, 
                                substr(a.dnis,-7,7) AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'TESTID' AS columnname, 
                                a.testid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'ACDID' AS columnname, 
                                a.acdid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'TestCaseNo' AS columnname, 
                                a.testcaseno AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'HostId' AS columnname, 
                                a.hostid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'TFN' AS columnname, 
                                a.tfn AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'INVALIDANI'                                  AS columnname, 
                                substr(concat(a.testcaseid ,a.testid),-10,10) AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual ) b ) 
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM            cte2 
    WHERE           profileid = pf; 

  END getenvvariables;
```

Then later on you can use this proc to return result in a ref_cursor variable.

```
DECALRE
       RES SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
     vatis_owner.Getenvvariables(pf, 
                                 sn,
                                 RES);
     FOR I IN 1..RES.COUNT LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.YOUR_DESIRED_COLUMNS);
     END LOOP;
END;
```

I can see that you are using CROSS APPLY in your query that means you must be using version 12C or higher. So you can use DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT function -

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE vatis_owner.Getenvvariables(pf IN VARCHAR, 
                                                        sn IN VARCHAR) AS 
  RES SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN 
    --Joins environemt variables from TESTCASES and ENVIRONMENTS tables and transposes result into columns 'ColumnName' and 'ColumnValue' and the ProfileId
    --Is used by getAllDynamicData and unioned with results from sp_getProfileDetails 
    OPEN RES FOR
    WITH cte AS 
    ( 
              SELECT    t.testcaseid, 
                        t.profileid, 
                        t.trustid, 
                        t.dnis, 
                        t.testid, 
                        t.acdid, 
                        --Must be 8 digits long, so leading 0's are added 
                        Substr(Concat('00000000',t.testcaseid),-8, 8) AS testcaseno, 
                        t.hostid, 
                        e.tfn 
              FROM      testcases t 
              full join environments e 
              ON        t.env_name = e.env_name 
                        --Only returns env vars associated with testcase @SN 
              WHERE     t.testcaseid = sn ), cte2 AS 
    ( 
           SELECT a.profileid , 
                  b.* 
           FROM   cte a 
                  --Transpose happens here 
                  cross apply 
                  ( 
                         SELECT 'TestcaseID' AS columnname, 
                                a.testcaseid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'ProfileID' AS columnname, 
                                a.profileid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'TrustID' AS columnname, 
                                a.trustid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'DNIS'              AS columnname, 
                                substr(a.dnis,-7,7) AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'TESTID' AS columnname, 
                                a.testid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'ACDID' AS columnname, 
                                a.acdid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'TestCaseNo' AS columnname, 
                                a.testcaseno AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'HostId' AS columnname, 
                                a.hostid AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'TFN' AS columnname, 
                                a.tfn AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 'INVALIDANI'                                  AS columnname, 
                                substr(concat(a.testcaseid ,a.testid),-10,10) AS columnvalue 
                         FROM   dual ) b ) 
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM            cte2 
    WHERE           profileid = pf;

    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(RES); 

  END getenvvariables;
```

When you will run this proc, You will see the result on console. For further information, Please [read.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1)

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up going with your first option, which also helped me return the output from a different stored procedure. I think I understand Oracle procedures a little better now.